# Add active and current state class

Tags: jquery

How can i give each , an active and current class to style with css , so onclick i get an active state , and onload i get a current class added. So each set at the same time will both have a current class added to the div.toggle that is loaded , and an active class added to when you tab to another

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ZM9dL/534/

I tried this , which add an active class , but it only shows up active for the one set of tabs your viewing , and removes the active class of the other set

```
var selector = '.tabbed-reports li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Here is html

```
<ul class="tabbed-reports">
    <li class="toggle1">One</li>
    <li class="toggle2">Two</li>
    <li class="toggle3">Three</li>
    <li class="toggle4">Four</li>
    <li class="toggle5">Five</li>
</ul>

<div class="reports-content">
    <div class="toggle1"><li class="remove">remove</li>Here are the contents of 1..</div>
    <div class="toggle2" style="display:none;"><li class="remove">remove</li>Here are the contents of 2..</div>
    <div class="toggle3" style="display:none;"><li class="remove">remove</li>Here are the contents of 3...</div>
    <div class="toggle4" style="display:none;"><li class="remove">remove</li>Here are the contents of 4....</div>
    <div class="toggle5" style="display:none;"><li class="remove">remove</li>Here are the contents of 5.....</div>
</div>

<ul class="tabbed-reports">
    <li class="toggle11">One</li>
    <li class="toggle12">Two</li>
    <li class="toggle13">Three</li>
    <li class="toggle14">Four</li>
    <li class="toggle15">Five</li>
</ul>

<div class="reports-content">
    <div class="toggle11"><li class="remove">remove</li>Here are the contents of 11..</div>
    <div class="toggle12" style="display:none;"><li class="remove">remove</li>Here are the contents of 12..</div>
    <div class="toggle13" style="display:none;"><li class="remove">remove</li>Here are the contents of 13...</div>
    <div class="toggle14" style="display:none;"><li class="remove">remove</li>Here are the contents of 14....</div>
    <div class="toggle15" style="display:none;"><li class="remove">remove</li>Here are the contents of 15.....</div>
</div>


$('.tabbed-reports li').on('click',function(e){
    $('.reports-content>.'+ e.target.classList[0]).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by current state/active?  You want a particular one to be selected onload?

Comment: to style with css , i want a .active class tag and a .current class tag. So when i click the tab , i can style it to look different when its content is displaying

Comment: are you trying this http://jsfiddle.net/ZM9dL/533/?

Comment: no that changes both sets of tabs at same time , i just want a class added to style for css .active / .current

Comment: i still don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: when you click a tab , that li , gets a class added callled "active" so the html is now <li class="toggle1 active">One</li>

Comment: updated my question and jsfiddle to show , i added a active class , but it is only being applied to one set of tabs at a time , need it to apply to both sets

Comment: is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/ZM9dL/536/ or this http://jsfiddle.net/ZM9dL/537/?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83488/discussion-between-sushil-and-mshack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a `current` class to the tab that has the default content visible on page load which in this case is `toggle1` and `toggle11`

this is how your js should look like.

```
var selector = '.tabbed-reports li';

$(selector).on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

    var className = $(this).attr('class').replace('current', '');

    console.log($(this).parent().next('.reports-content'));
    $(this).parent().next('.reports-content').find('div').hide();

    $('.reports-content').find('.' + className).toggle();

    $(this).toggleClass('active');

});
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZM9dL/540/)**